# Including external libraries in Python SVN Repository

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, pydev, python-import

I've used SVN for a long time but am new to Python, so hopefully this is straight-forward to do:

I have a Python project that links to an SVN repository. This project imports external libraries (jar files, etc.) from the Python interpreter.

Is there a way to commit the project settings (libraries, etc.) such that a new user can do a checkout and be able to run it out of the box (assuming they have Python installed on their machine)?

I'm using [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).